# Не получается прикрутить событие android:onClick="onClick" к LinearLayout

Tags: события, android

Пытаюсь понять, почему сабж.

Часть главного layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnOpenWord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hint_add_word" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reward_coins"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Метод onClick вызывается в Активити с интерфейсом View.OnClickListener. Код Активити такой

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
      // Some code
}
if (v.getId() == R.id.btnOpenWord) {
              // Some code
            }           
}
```

Причем, при нажатии на элемент с АйДи R.id.imageView1 все работает. А с LinearLayout нет.

Лог ошибки:

```
10-09 13:31:20.860: E/AndroidRuntime(28160): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.LinearLayout with id 'btnOpenWord'</CODE>
```

Comment: советую никогда не выставлять лиснеры в xml.    
Из за этого и возникает путаница. Путается как программист, так и сам Эклипс.

Comment: Спасибо. Так и решил сделать. Все заработало. 
Вот лечение:
findViewById(R.id.btnOpenWord).setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно, к чему вы привязываете обработчик события onClickListener. Также непоянтно, что вы хотели сказать этим:

```
 Метод onClick вызывается в Активити
```

ну не в воздухе же он вызывается) Естественно, обработчиком выступает Activity, в пределах которой вызвавший событие виджет-наследник класса View расположен.

У вас не получается привязать обработчик к LinearLayout-виджету?

Здесь:

```
10-09 13:31:20.860: E/AndroidRuntime(28160): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.LinearLayout with id 'btnOpenWord'</CODE>
```

говорится о том, что вы пытаетесь привязать обработчик к тому, у чего его нет.
Также разберитесь, точно ли виджет с ID "btnOpenWord" существует.